# How to solve this error in docker toolbox running on windows 7 I tried configuring the virtual box by adding shared folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-toolbox, docker-run

```
$ docker run -p 3000:3000 -v "/app/node_modules" -v "$(pwd):/app" 4a1158abb76e
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-07T07_33_16_702Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I'd recommend deleting both `-v` options, since they overwrite the application code in the image and cause Docker to completely ignore any updates in your `package.json` file.  You can use a Node installation on your host for a live-development environment.

Comment: Is there any way to do that in docker I am new to Docker